# Scene's GameObjects light bleeding issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

Some of the gameobjects in my scene have a weird bleeding white light on the edges. It's not possible for them to have a light casted on them as there's no immediate light near it.

[image]

[image]

Whats the reason for this? Is this because of incorrect placement of light probes?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using light baking; probably something with the geometry or the baking settings,